# Angular 2 Handling scenarios when the user enters a valid URL manually in the address bar.

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to handle scenarios when the user types a valid url on the address bar. 
I have implemented canActivate and canDeactivate Interfaces. 
Is there a way to detect if the user entered the url from the address bar or if his navigating withing the app led him there?

Comment: Why would you want to act differently depending on wether the user accessed the route via address bar?

Comment: This components gets reuse and depending on how is being navigated into, the data is acquire in different ways.

Comment: That sounds like really bad practice.